# Custom views in toolbar like Airbnb explore screen

Tags: android, android-toolbar, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I want to add multiple input fields in top bar area of application (toolbar) for search purposes of my app. I see that Airbnb does that at its best! I have tried various scenarios using AppBarLayout in CoordinatorLayout but it all failed. Is it possible to get the same or similar effect? If yes, how do we do that?

Here are the screenshots when I swipe down the top bar:

[image: first it show only one compact field]
[image: compact field disappears while real input fields come into screen]
[image: compact field is gone, all real input fields are on the screen]

Comment: Have you solved this issue?

Comment: No. I tried to get similar effect by putting some views in a layout wrapped inside a CoordinatorLayout but it was not the same. I left this design attempt at the end.

Answer (score 0):

> Yes it is possible to create using appbar layout, I have tried same task, Finally i have figured-out in this way, I guess below code is helpful for you

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <!--your toolbar-->
        <include
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_wrapper"
            layout="@layout/common_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
                android:id="@+id/appbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/color_fafafa"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:background="@color/color_ffffff"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll">

                    <!--your scrolling layout, in your case it will be edit texts and search fields-->
                </LinearLayout>
            </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

                <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                    android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/dp_49"
                    android:background="@color/color_ffffff"
                    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
                    app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/colorAccent"
                    app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/color_727272"
                    app:tabTextColor="@color/color_b6b6b6" />

                <View
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/dp_1"
                    android:background="@color/color_d9d9d9" />
                <!--your main layout-->
                <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                    android:id="@+id/detail_pager"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true" />
            </LinearLayout>

        </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</layout>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are still looking for an answer, I tried to do something similar. My layout is

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:ignore="RtlHardcoded">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/main.appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/main.collapsing"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed|snap">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:visibility="invisible"
                app:contentInsetEnd="0dp"
                app:contentInsetStart="0dp">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/summarized_search_layout"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="top|center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="12dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/background_blue_light_rounded"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:padding="12dp"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="none">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="20dp"
                        android:layout_height="20dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:src="@drawable/menu_search" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/summarized_search_text"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:layout_marginStart="12dp" />

                </LinearLayout>

            </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/extended_search_layout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                app:layout_collapseParallaxMultiplier="1">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="12dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/background_blue_light_rounded"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:padding="12dp">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="20dp"
                        android:layout_height="20dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:src="@drawable/menu_profile" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:layout_marginStart="12dp" />

                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="12dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/background_blue_light_rounded"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:padding="12dp">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="20dp"
                        android:layout_height="20dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:src="@drawable/menu_calendar" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:layout_marginStart="12dp" />

                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="12dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/background_blue_light_rounded"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:padding="12dp">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="20dp"
                        android:layout_height="20dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:src="@drawable/menu_poi" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:layout_marginStart="12dp" />

                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="12dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/background_blue_light_rounded"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:padding="12dp">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="20dp"
                        android:layout_height="20dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:src="@drawable/menu_poi" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:layout_marginStart="12dp" />

                </LinearLayout>

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/validation_button"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="end"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="12dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                    android:text="GO" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tablayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:tabGravity="fill"
            app:tabMode="fixed">

            <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Search" />

            <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Popular" />

            <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Favorites" />

        </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>

        <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scrollbars="none">

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="8dp"
                app:cardElevation="8dp"
                app:contentPadding="16dp">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:lineSpacingExtra="8dp"
                    android:text="@string/lorem"
                    android:textSize="18sp" />
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


        </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

    </LinearLayout>


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

You can see I use a `Toolbar` with `visibility = invisible` to force my layout to stay partialy visible. I am not really proud of that trick but I failed to find an other solution.

Once you have your layout it's just a matter of animation depending on the progress of the offset.

If you succeed, I would be happy to see your code because I'm not really happy with mine.

I hope it can help you.